# Why is multiplication not always commutative in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multiplication, commutativity

If `x` is a non-integer, I get this result:

```
x = "a"
x * 6 #=> aaaaaa
6 * x #=> TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

whereas if `x` is an integer:

```
x = 6
x * 6 #=> 36
6 * x #=> 36
```

It's strange that the operand order in multiplication matters if `x` is a non-integer, and not if `x` is an integer. Can someone explain what the rational is behind this? When `x` is a string, why must variable `x` precede the `*` operator to avoid raising an error?

Comment: Precedence has nothing to do with this situation.

Answer (score 4):

1. You have a typo in your latter snippet: it should start with `x = 6` (without quotes.)
2. Everything in Ruby is an object, including instances of `String`, `Integer`, even `nil` which is [the only] instance of `NilClass`.

That said, there is no *just an operator* `*`. It’s a plain old good method, declared on different classes, that is called by the *operator `*`* (thanks @SergioTulentsev for picky wording comment.) Here is a doc for [`String#*`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-2A), other you might find yourself. And `"a" * 6` is nothing else, than:

```
"a".*(6)
```

You might check the above in your console: it’s a perfectly valid Ruby code. So, different classes have different implementations of `*` method, hence the different results above.

Comment: It [_is_ an operator](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y#L1935), though. It is resolved to a message handler (method), yes, but it is recognized as a special case in the language. As a consequence, you [can't define arbitrary operators](https://gist.github.com/stulentsev/ba5311c3c796f024bc6c59227448d491) (because parser doesn't know about them).

Comment: _"Everything in Ruby is an object, including String, Integer"_ – although `String` and `Integer` are objects too, you are probably referring to **instances** of `String` and `Integer`.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying three patterns here:

- a. `string * numeric`
- b. `numeric * string`
- c. `numeric * numeric`

The behavior of a method and what arguments are required primarily depends on what is on the left side of the method (`*` in this case), on which the method is defined. No method (including `*`) is commutative per se.

`String#*` requires the first argument to be a numeric, which a. satisfies, and `Numeric#*` requires the first argument to be a numeric, which c. satisfies, and b. does not.

Comment: Is there a rational for string/numeric to require the first argument to be a numerical? Or this is just how Ruby works?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ruby in particular. This is how OO works. The receiver of a message gets to decide what he does with the message. That is the *fundamental* feature of OO. OO is *fundamentally* non-commutative. In `a.foo(b)`, it is `a` which gets to decide how to interpret `foo`, in `b.foo(a)`, it is `b` which gets to decide. In order for `foo` to be commutative, `a` and `b` have to agree to cooperate on a shared definition of `foo`. In this case, they don't.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand what the method `*` does.<sup>1</sup>. That depends on the method's *receiver*. For `"cat".*(3)`, `"cat"` is `*`'s receiver. For `1.*(3)` (which, as explained later, can be written, `1*3`) `1` is `*`'s receiver. The term "receiver" derives from OOP's concept of sending a message (method) to a receiver.

A method can be defined on an object (e.g., `"cat"` or `1`) in one of two ways. The most common is that the method is an *instance method* defined on the receiver's class (e.g., `*` defined on `"cat".class #=> String` or `1.class #=> Integer`. The second way, which is not applicable here, is that the method has been defined on the object's *singleton class*, provided the object has one. (`"cat"` has a singleton class but `1`, being an *immediate value*, does not.)

When we see `"cat".*(3)`, therefore, we look to the doc for [String#*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-2A) and conclude that

```
"cat".*(3) #=> "catcatcat"
```

For `1*(3)`, we look to [Integer#*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-2A), which tells us that

```
1.*(3) #=> 3
```

Let's try another: `[1,2,3].*(3)`, Because `[1,2,3].class #=> Array` we look to [Array#*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-2A) and conclude that

```
[1,2,3].*(3) #=> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Note that this method has two forms, depending on whether its argument is an integer (as here) or a string. In the latter case

```
[1,2,3].*(' or ') #=> "1 or 2 or 3"
```

Many methods have different behaviors that depend on its arguments (and on whether an optional block is provided).

Lastly, Ruby allows us to use a shorthand with these three methods (and certain others with names comprised of characters that are not letters, numbers or underscores.):

```
"cat"*3     #=> "catcatcat"
"cat" * 3   #=> "catcatcat"
1*3         #=> 3
[1,2,3] * 3 #=> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

This shorthand is generally referred to as "syntactic sugar".

<sup>1 Ruby's method names are not restricted to words, such as "map", "upcase"
 and so on. "*", "~", "[]" and "[]=", for example, are valid method names"</sup>

Comment: As mentioned in my comment to @mudasobwa's answer, the list of the methods which have this sugar is hardcoded in the parser. So it can't be _any_ non-alphanumeric name.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the result can also differ when changing the  argument (instead of the receiver), e.g. `[1,2,3] * ","` returns the string `"1,2,3"`